# Mariadb equivalent to MySQL CONNECTION_CONTROL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, security, connections

MySQL introduced a security plugin library in version 5.7.17 including the plugin CONNECTION_CONTROL, which checks incoming connection attempts and adds a delay to server responses as a result of failed attempts.
I have checked the Mariadb documentation but cannot find an equivalent. What would be the preferred way in Mariadb to achieve the same function?

Comment: From [Is there a MariaDB equivalent to MySQL CONNECTION_CONTROL plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/is-there-a-mariadb-equivalent-to-mysql-connection_control-plugin/) there isn't something equivalent like *MySQL CONNECTION_CONTROL* in MariaDB

Comment: Thanks Ergest. Will have to find a workaround, possibly with max_password_errors

Comment: There only minor code changes to [connection_control](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/5.7/plugin/connection_control) to copy it into the mariadb source code plugin tree and copmile there. This acts as a audit plugin. (disclaimer I've only done a 10 minute attempt to get the compile errors below 9 and hasn't been run).